# Allow HTTP request retry under certain conditions using Got

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I’m using the [Got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) library for HTTP requests within my application. I’m making HTTP requests to an API where I can expect an HTTP code 404 under certain conditions. I’d like to use Got's internal retry functionality for rerunning the request until the 404 error is gone (which will happen; I just don't know if it takes 1 minute or 30 minutes).

From the documentation I know that HTTP code 404 is not a supported statusCode for the built-in retry functionality and therefore I cannot perform any action within the beforeRetry hook of Got; see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#retry).

I’m extending a Got instance to allow some presets for the API I’m calling. For now I have not found a clean way to extend the existing retry statusCodes with 404.

```
const gitlabOnPrem = got.extend({
    prefixUrl: ".." + "..",
    mutableDefaults: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    //retry: { statusCode: got.defaults.options.retry.statusCode.push(404) }, //does not work | not clean
    https: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    headers: {
        'PRIVATE-TOKEN': "..",
        Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    hooks: {
        beforeError: [
            (error) => {
                const { response } = error;
                console.log(response);
                /*
                Another idea: if I cannot extend retry statusCodes then I´d like to somehow force a retry from here
                if (response.statusCode === 404 && response.path.endsWith('/export/download')) {
                    console.log('FORCE A RETRY AS THE DOWNLOAD MIGHT NOT BE READY YET');
                }
                */

                if (response && response.body) {
                    error.name = 'GitLabOnPremError';
                    error.message = `${response.body.message !== undefined
                            ? response.body.message
                            : response.body.error
                        } (${response.statusCode})`;
                }

                return error;
            },
        ],
    },
});
```

1. How can I extend the HTTP statusCodes that allow running a retry?
2. If this is not possible, see my comment in the code. Is it somehow possible to force a retry manually by just using Got?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's best to just write it yourself. Trying to get a library to work in a way that it isn't totally made to do can be more pain than it's worth. It's also usually very brittle in the long run.

Why not just wrap it yourself? Something like this:

```js
async function MyGotFn() {

    let retries = 100;
    let statusCode = 404;
    let response;

    while (statusCode === 404 && --retries > 0) {
        response = await got('...');
        statusCode = response.statusCode;
    }

    if (response.statusCode === 404) throw new Error('max retries reached');

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure that's a way of overcoming this issue. Just hoped to learn about a smart way of doing it by using lib utils. But nevertheless thanks for the advice. I´ll keep the Q open, maybe someone knows how to do it by extending the got object.

Comment: What if, like Request, Got was dropped tomorrow, or the Got API changes in the next release? By all means if something is convenient use it. Fix the problem only _if_ it ever happens. But why work _harder_ to write something in a "smart" way that is actually _poorer_ code?

Comment: What if node will be dropped tomorrow, then your 15 lines wont be future proofed as well :P  I mean I get your point, but it's definitly not poorer code the way I would like to have it, it would be even cleaner as you can write your hooks just in the config module and dont have to transport those logic in your service classes. This question is also about investigating how certain things can work, not spending my time as cost/ time efficient as possible. But I get what you want to say, all fine! Thanks buddy